# How to set up the relayhost to send emails to other external SMTP servers using PostFIX?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, vps

I am currently configuring an SMTP server on OCI but have some doubts. I would like to send emails with my domain to external servers such as GMAIL, OUTLOOK, and others.

I had configured the "relayhost" with my domain and port 587, but it started requesting SASL authentication. So, I removed it and tried again, and I noticed that it was using the external GMAIL server to send emails.

How should the configuration be done in this case?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Use an relayhost, or have your server go directly to the recipients MX?

Comment: I would like my MX to reach other mailboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use relay host when you want to send mail to Google and so on.

You would need your postfix server to configure an sending only mta, preferably using smtp over tls. You can use letsencrypt for the tls/ssl part

See also here for some guidance
https://gist.github.com/lodi-g/9f89d102aa51e9e50da5d7954ddc5917

```
myhostname = hostname
    myorigin = domain 
    mydomain = domain 
    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, example.com
    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
    relay_domains = 
    relay_host =  
    smtpd_relay_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks 
    permit_sasl_authenticated 
    defer_unauth_destination


smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/fullchain.pem
        smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/privkey.pem
        smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
        smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
        smtpd_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
        smtp_tls_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
        smtp_tls_ciphers = high
        smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
        smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
        smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, !TLSv1, !SSLv2, !SSLv3
        smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
        smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = high
        smtpd_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
        smtpd_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
        smtp_tls_mandatory_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
        smtp_tls_exclude_ciphers = MD5, DES, ADH, RC4, PSD, SRP, 3DES, eNULL, aNULL
        tls_preempt_cipherlist = yes
        smtpd_tls_security_level = may
        smtp_tls_security_level = may
        smtpd_tls_loglevel = 2
        smtp_tls_loglevel = 2
        smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

I assumed you know how to request certificates with letsencrypt

If you only want to send mails to certain domains you can configure that in the `mydestination` directive, which is used to specify the list of domains that are delivered through the mail delivery transport